# UINavigationBar prevent resize in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, uinavigationbar, landscape

I have an `UINavigationController` which holds a viewController. This viewController presents a fullscreen, landscape-only viewController either via a button or on device rotation to landscape.

When using the button, the status bar disappears for portrait and the navigation bar jumps to top (that's not nice – actually quite ugly – but not the core problem).

When rotating the device, the portrait viewController does not only "lose" the status bar (as expected) but its navigationBar resizes to a narrow height of 35px.

44px in portrait
[image: navigationBar height portrait]

35px in landscape
[image: navigationBar height landscape]

Since the fullscreen viewController covers this, it might seem unimportant. But in my case, the content, which has some special scroll-animations, produces an unpleasant glitch that doesn't disappear after dismissal.

All my viewControllers implement

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

except of the fullscreen-landscape-only viewController which implements

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

How can I not only prevent orientation change, but also size class (??) changes?